# Facebook Java SDK not loading

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am i using facebook sdk in my app after initializing the facebook init method and running the app under the canvas i am getting this error on console.

```
`Blocked a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.*****.com". The frame requesting access set "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow ac`cess.
```

But i am using the app direct from the url its not showing any errors

Please help

Comment: You should add a short code snippet that demonstrates the behavior.

Comment: Are you calling the SDK from the same IP configured in facebook app developer console?

Comment: Yes i am calling it from the same IP that i configured in canvas url